# Best way(s) to add new king stud to existing exterior wall

Tags: windows, framing, exterior, studs

I'm going to be removing a large 4'wide x 7'tall window and replacing it with a small 3'x2' window.

I will probably need to add a couple of new king studs when framing up and to keep everything 16" on center.

This is all new to me so I'm looking for ideas on ways to add the new king studs.

For example, should I "toenail" the studs in? I've seen techniques where people use their pocket hole jig and come in at a 45 degree and and screw in the new studs.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you're adding pin studs or trimmers under the header, and not kings, but yes.

Insert the new trimmers before anything else and stand them vertical, then add the inner trimmers (assuming you want doubled studs for strength and trim backing). Move the trimmer pairs into position and toenail them to the header using either framing nails or construction screws.

Comment: Is it considered a trimmer because it was not originally added for bearing weight? Or is it because it's being added after the fact? Sorry, if this is a stupid question.

Comment: King studs run full-height outside the header. I'm assuming that you're leaving the existing header in place, so all new framing is underneath it.

Comment: I wasn't really thinking there was a header because the windows were so tall. I was thinking maybe it was a long beam that went across. But not that I think about it there probably is a header over each of the tall windows. I was thinking that I would be nailing directly into the top plate, but now that I think about it, you're probably right. I've added a picture to my post so you can see how big the windows are that I'm dealing with.

Comment: There may be a single full-span header. There may also be individual headers with kings and trimmers between windows. The situation is probably the same in either case.